# Determine country based on same country code

Tags: php, country-codes

I have a list of all the countries based on their STD dialing codes for example +91 for India, +1 for USA,etc.

Based on dialing code, i can easily pick country. For example with +213 code, i can get Algeria as country.

But for +1 dialing code, i get more than one result(USA, Canada, Jamaica, Puerto Rico). Is there a way i can differentiate between them ?

Is there a way to manage them easily and get required result ?

If user is dialing +1 for Jamaica, he should get country Jamaica and not USA or any other.

Let me know

Comment: Can you provide any code that you have test?

Comment: I guess you are going to have to look deeper and also check the Area Code in these situations

Comment: country code is +1 in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it has a 1, can you then put in some code to look at the next numbers, which should then indicate the country / island / region?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Numbering_Plan

Comment: can you please elaborate as +44 is code for United Kingdom, Guernsey, Isle of Man, Guernsey how can i differentiate these.

Comment: For the united kingdom, the next 5 numbers following the +44 select the area.  The channel islands are an area in exactly the same way as Central London. please see: https://www.ofcom.org.uk/phones-telecoms-and-internet/advice-for-consumers/advice/telephone-area-codes-tool.